# The number of processes a user is running using bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I would like to know how I could get the number of processes for each user that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
ps -u "$(echo $(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u))" o user= | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

In order to properly handle usernames that may be longer than eight characters, use `users` instead of `w`. The latter truncates usernames.

```
ps -u "$(echo $(printf '%s\n' $(users) | sort -u))" o user= | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: Unfortunately `w -h` truncates user names to 8 characters, it also only lists the logged on users so you don't get a view of all users, just logon users.

Comment: @OliverDungey: The OP asked for users that are currently logged in. If you want processes for all users regardless of whether they're logged in then you don't need `w` - you can just use `ps` (which can be made to show the long usernames in full). The `users` command shows logged in users and appears to not truncate the names. My answer could be adapted to use it. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 13):

You could try some variation of this:

```
ps haux Ou | cut '-d ' -f1 | uniq -c
```

It gives you the number of processes for each users (being logged in or not). Now you could filter those results using the output of the w command or another way of determining who is logged in.

Comment: Nice!  Could add a `grep ' pts\| tty'` before the cut, would cut out any process not tied to a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

```
ps -u aboelnour | awk 'END {print NR}'
```

will show number of process which user aboelnour running it

Answer (score 3):

If you are ever concerned about nearing the user process limit shown by `ulimit -a`, the you want to get ALL the processes (including LWPs).  In such a case you should use:

```
ps h -Led -o user | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

On one system doing this:

```
ps haux Ou | cut '-d ' -f1 | uniq -c
```

yields:

```
# ps haux Ou | cut '-d ' -f1 | uniq -c
 30 user1
  1 dbus
  3 user2
  1 ntp
  1 nut
  1 polkitd
  2 postfix
124 root
  2 serv-bu+
```

where doing the former yields the true process count:

```
# ps h -Led -o user | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
  1 ntp
  1 nut
  2 dbus
  2 postfix
  2 serv-builder
  3 user2
  6 polkitd
141 root
444 user1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
lslogins -o USER,PROC
```

Comment: Nice. Was introduced in 2014, 4 years after the question, and until today I hadn't stumbled upon it =}

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a count of processes you can use procfs directly like this:
(requires linux 2.2 or greater)

you can use wc:

```
number_of_processes=`echo /proc/[0-9]* | wc -w`
```

or do it in pure bash (no external commands) like this

```
procs=( /proc/[0-9]* ) 
number_of_proccesses=${#procs[*]}
```

If you only want the current userid

```
procs=( /proc/[0-9]*/fd/. ) 
number_of_proccesses=${#procs[*]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following links contain useful [ps commands options](http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/ps.php) including your requirements:

- [Displaying all processes owned by a specific user](http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/ps.php)
- [Show All Running Processes in Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

```
userlist=$(w|awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","}NR>2{print $1}'|sed 's/,$//' )
ps -u "$userlist"
```

Comment: I have used this in combination with Aboelnour's answer but it gives me the number of processes without the corresponding user of those processes.Any idea on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, for Linux:

$ find /proc –user $USER -maxdepth 1 -name '[0-9]*' | wc –l

This solution will not fail when the number of processes is larger than the command line limit.