# Bash Script Find all processes based on USER

Tags: linux, bash

I have an assigment where I am supposed to make a bashscript that finds all processes from USER based on the argument that is being passed.

```
#! /bin/bash
argument=$1

ps aux | grep -w $argument
```

This kinda works, but what I really want is only processes from specific USER and I have no idea how to do it. I tried using regular expression but I can't seem to use arguments inside ' '. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the argument, process name ?

Comment: The argument is USER.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You had to make an effort to avoid an answer... [How to see process created by specific user in Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85466/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [The number of processes a user is running using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3874677/608639) on Stack Overflow, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The user name is typically listed as the first item in each line of the `ps -aux` output. There is usually a space separating the User Name from the second item. Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash
argument="$1"
ps aux | grep "^$argument "
```

This regular expression starts at the beginning of each line and looks for the `$argument` followed by a space.

Comment: God damn, this was my initial idea all along. But for some reason I wrote "^\$argument" and it didn't work, so I thought this wasn't the way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherToussi should you give me a thumbs up instead of a thumbs down?